# Criar uma variavel com o valor do input e addEventListener "keypress"

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Galera, estou tentando pegar o valor isolado de alguns inputs quando digitado no input.

Até consigo logar o valor digitado. ex: console.log(topLeft.value), que retorna o valor que está presente no input no momento e algo 'undefined'.

Queria que o valor que está presente no input se tornasse o valor de uma váriavel.

Ja tentei criar variáveis fora das funções com o nome do lado correspondenete (ex let topLeft;) porem a mesma não armazena o valor do input.

Sou iniciante no assunto e queria saber aonde estou errando.

```js
function getElemento(getElement) {
    topLeft = getElement("tl");
    topRight = getElement("tr");
    bottomLeft = getElement("bl");
    bottomRight = getElement("br");
}
function addEvento(addEvent){
    addEvent(topLeft);
    addEvent(topRight);
    addEvent(bottomLeft);
    addEvent(bottomRight);
}

window.onload = () => {
    function getInputValue() {
        let inputValue = this.value;
        return inputValue
    };
    function getElement(id){
        let element = document.getElementById(id);
        return element
    };
    function addEvent (side){
        side.addEventListener("keypress", getInputValue);
    };
    getElemento(getElement);
    addEvento(addEvent)
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/value.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <p>
            <label for="top-left">Top Left:</label>
            <input  id="tl" name="top-left" type="number" value="0">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="top-right">Top Right:</label>
            <input type="number" id="tr" name="top-right" value="0">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="bottom-left">Bottom Left:</label>
            <input type="number" id="bl" name="bottom-left" value="0">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="bottom-right">Bottom Right:</label>
            <input type="number" id="br" name="bottom-right" value="0">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloque o HTML para termos uma noção do funcionamento do código.

Comment: Codigo HTML adicionado.

Comment: Você quer tirar uma variável de dentro do _callback_ do evento?

Comment: Acredito que sim, queria um váriavel com o valor do input, no momento que o valor é digitado, o callback do evento extrai o valor dá variavel que contem o input e retorna o seu valor, mas não enxergo como extrai-lo

Comment: O que queres fazer com esse valor do input? ainda não percebi o teu objetivo

Comment: Posteriormente usar como valores para um border-radius no css, mas será outro aprendizado

Comment: Pode retornar os valores dos `inputs` para quatro variáveis globais? Uma específica para cada input?

Comment: Esse é o objetivo, como eu deveria proceder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você generalizou a instalação de um mesmo eventos para todos os seus `inputs` e quando você precisou buscar um valor de um input específico você ficou sem saída... ou quase.

A solução para esse impasse é fazer a verificação do `id`(ou outro atributo que o identifique, ex: [atributos data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)) do elemento que gerou o evento e destinar o valor desse elemento ao seu destino com base nesse `id`.

No caso eu não sei qual seria o destino dos valores desses `inputs` então criei quatro variáveis globais `tL`, `tR`, `bL` e `bR` e um botão que loga os seus valores.

Na função `getInputValue()` eu adicionei uma verificação do `id` do elemento que disparou o evento e destino o seu valor a `tL`, `tR`, `bL` e `bR` com base nesse id:

```js
let tL = 0;
let tR = 0;
let bL = 0;
let bR = 0;

function getElemento(getElement) {
  topLeft = getElement("tl");
  topRight = getElement("tr");
  bottomLeft = getElement("bl");
  bottomRight = getElement("br");
}

function addEvento(addEvent) {
  addEvent(topLeft);
  addEvent(topRight);
  addEvent(bottomLeft);
  addEvent(bottomRight);
}

window.onload = () => {
  function getInputValue() {
    let inputValue = this.value;
    //Verifica o id do elemento que disparou o evento
    //e atribui seu valor a sua respectiva variável
    switch (this.id) {
      case "tl":
        tL = inputValue;
        break;
      case "tr":
        tR = inputValue;
        break;
      case "bl":
        bL = inputValue;
        break;
      case "br":
        bR = inputValue;
        break;
    }
    return inputValue
  };

  function getElement(id) {
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    return element
  };

  function addEvent(side) {
    //Aqui troquei o evento keypress por input que é mais adequado
    side.addEventListener("input", getInputValue);
  };
  getElemento(getElement);
  addEvento(addEvent)
}

function imprimir() {
  console.log(`${tL}, ${tR}, ${bL}, ${bR}`);
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/value.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="">
    <p>
      <label for="top-left">Top Left:</label>
      <input id="tl" name="top-left" type="number" value="0">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="top-right">Top Right:</label>
      <input type="number" id="tr" name="top-right" value="0">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="bottom-left">Bottom Left:</label>
      <input type="number" id="bl" name="bottom-left" value="0">
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="bottom-right">Bottom Right:</label>
      <input type="number" id="br" name="bottom-right" value="0">
    </p>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="imprimir()" value="Imprimir variáveis" /></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

MDN Evento input: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: Augusto, muito obrigado por apresentar a solução! Entedi, errei no momento em que quis deixar o código sem muitas repetições e nem imaginava o uso do switch! Agora é continuar os estudos, obrigado a todos! E ainda aprendi um novo evento que imaginava que existia mas não tinha encontrado...